# ImportError: No module named twilio.rest while using twilio in server

Tags: python, pip, twilio

I have tried to work on simple Twilio script in the server after using command :

```
pip install twilio==6.0`
```

Even though Twilio installed successfully am getting the following error:

```
No module named twilio.rest for the line  
No module named twilio.rest
```

Can someone help what is the issue?

Comment: Can you add the code that you've tried or traceback the full error ?

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio and I'd like to help, but as Vikas has asked, can you add the code you're using and perhaps how you're running that code too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @VikasDamodar . i found the issue is not with installation but i failed to activate my virtualenv before installing the twilio.Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not using different versions of Python.

Try using `pip2` with `python2` or `pip3` with `python3` commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
 pip3 install twilio==6.0
```

Its worked for me. As python3 installed in my server.